# Million photographs of a falling rock. Expected value of the fallen distance?

Tags: probability

Let's take a rock falling from height $h$ and we take a million photographs, during the time it falls. What is the expected value of the distance it fell on the photos?

The textbook (Introduction to Quantum Mechanics by David J. Griffiths) solves this example by approximating the million photographs with a "continuum" of them, and then the solution goes by:

1. Probability of a photo taken in interval $[t, t+dt]$: $dp=\frac{dt}{T}$ where $T=\sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}}$ is the falling time.
2. Probability of a rock being between distances $[x(t), x(t)+dx]$ on the photo taken in the above time interval, derived from $x=\frac{1}{2}gt^2$: $dp=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{hx}}dx$, thus the probability density is $\rho(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{hx}}$.
3. Finally, the expected value of the fallen distance of the rock on a photo is: $\int_0^hx\rho(x)dx=\frac{h}{3}$.

This is all well and good, I know this is a good approximation, but as the book says "a statician would complain that I'm confusing the average of a finite samle with the true average over the continuum", and neither am I satisfied with this solution completely. I would like to know how to solve it with taking into account that there are only finitely many photographs, but I cannot start, since I was always bad at probability theory. Please give me at least some advice, or a sketch that I can work out on how to solve this problem "properly" (at least more properly than the presented solution). Thank you.

Comment: Surely the expected height is $2h/3$?

Comment: @TonyK No, it's only $h/3$.

Comment: $h/3$ is the expected value of the fallen distance. So the expected value of the _height_ is $2h/3$.

Comment: @TonyK I'm sorry, you're right. I'll edit the question.

Comment: You need to be clearer about the assumptions. If you took the photos with the same camera, there would be some latency (ie a minimum interval between photos). But assume that the timing of each photo is uniformly distributed over the period of the fall and all the timings are independent. You have calculated the distribution for each one. You now use the Central Limit Theorem to deduce that the distribution for the mean fall has mean h/3 and standard deviation 1/1000 x that for a single photo. You can calculate the SD for a single photo, but it is obv less than h.

Comment: @almagest Thank you for the comment on the assumptions. I have to think about your solution though, but I'll think I understand.

Comment: Intervals of the photographs are random..... If not the next value greater than zero is the answer.